# Java Memory : jstat vs Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory, memory-management

I am running a java application where i have observed below :

through code i am calculating memory utilization :

```
long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
this.memUsage = 100f - (freeMemory*100)/this.maxMemory;
where
instance.maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

Timestamp         S0     S1     E      **O**      P     YGC     YGCT    FGC    FGCT     GCT

2849.6   0.00  84.80  93.14  **16.95**  60.00    483  140.140     8    3.649  143.789

First of all my code will show which memory.Old, Eden or Survivor.I think Old..m i rgt ??

At particular time, I am observing that my code give me different output compare to jstat old memory utilization.
Like here jstat old show approx 17 % and my code shows 20%. Any reason for this ??

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the Runtime memory methods only report about the HEAP as a total (so all the values are totals of old, eden, survivor and permanent).  This is why your values would be off, as there isn't a jstat output telling you the overall heap utilization.

One thing to note about `Runtime.freeMemory()` is that it may not be entirely accurate.  From the javadoc of the method:

*Returns **an approximation** to the total amount of memory currently available for future allocated objects, measured in bytes.*

I tend to not trust any of the values returned from the Runtime class about memory.  Either use an external command like jconsole or jstat to get the memory stats, or use `-Xloggc` when launching the java program.  These ways are much more reliable for monitoring memory usage than any of the API methods I've seen.